# Android : Is there any way to change the default language of android to new language?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to know whether it is possible to change the default android OS language to other. For which the language is not in the settings for instance: how to set the device 's language to burmese programmatically.

Comment: Are you talking about doing this *in code*?

Comment: @John Skeet : pls see my updated question. Yes i need to do it programmatically.

Comment: Are you looking developing android apps in other platforms except java?

Comment: @F4L : No, i'm using only java to develop android apps...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use this to change the language by programmatically--

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en_US");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
context.getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
```

Write the countrycode of language in place of "en_US" whatever language you want...like for japanese--"ja_JP" For Arabic--"ar" or check this link for code of country--

http://code.google.com/apis/igoogle/docs/i18n.html

And make a folder in **res/values-ja** for japanese or **res/values-ar** for arabic..

And make **string.xml file** And put the languages whatever you want on your layout.. It will fetch the default language from values folder otherwise you want it manually then it will fetch from your external folder values-ar etc. like...

Its example of **res/values-ar for arabic**--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <resources>
    <string name="spinner_label">تصفية حسب</string>
    <string name="app_name">2011 فرق</string> 
    <string name="search">بحث :</string>
</resource>
```

Hope It will help you..

Comment: Good answer Hulk sir. I am using same code in my projcet(Diff) :P

Comment: Where to put this code Local.setDefault ? in the MainActivity.java?

Comment: You need to put this in onCreate() of every activity. Otherwise it may get overridden by the system - for instance when you turn your device to landscape and your activity gets recreated with new (system provided) configuration.

Comment: This is a great solution - I have one problem with it, though. If I change the locale to a RTL locale like "ar" then although the language resource qualifier (-ar) is working (e.g. arabic strings are used in my app), the layout direction res qualifier (-ldrtl) is not working. Android fetches resources still from RESFOLDER and not from RESFOLDER-ldrtl. :( Any solution for that?

Comment: In case you set a RTL locale like "ar" and want your -ldrtl resource folders to work as well then also call config.setLayoutDirection(locale);

Comment: context.getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration is deprecated

Answer (score 3):

you can change the locale to whatever you want and the system need support it.

try this:

```
public static void changeLocale(Locale locale) {
    try {
        Class<?> activityManagerNative = Class.forName("android.app.ActivityManagerNative");

        Object am = activityManagerNative.getMethod("getDefault").invoke(activityManagerNative);

        Object config = am.getClass().getMethod("getConfiguration").invoke(am);
        config.getClass().getDeclaredField("locale").set(config, locale);
        config.getClass().getDeclaredField("userSetLocale").setBoolean(config, true);

        am.getClass().getMethod("updateConfiguration", android.content.res.Configuration.class).invoke(am, config);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "send change locale request");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "change locale error:", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this code change the default language to other new language ?

Comment: yes, the burmese locale may like `Locale locale = new Locale("my")`, but your device need support this language otherwise the system dont change the language.

Comment: +1 for this useful info. But what if the device doesn't have built-in burmese language and i have to make it to work in all devices?

Comment: we can't add the language support in programming code, it need change the firmware or rom, so we can't do that -):

Comment: @Raman-Mystry - what is the point of changing the language to something that the device doesn't support?  Surely you should be asking of ways to **add** support for the language / locale.

Comment: @Stephen C : to maintain the Localization among all the devices

Comment: @idiottiger: +1 and thank you for this useful info, are you sure that we can't change the non inbuilt language such as burmese language?

Comment: This code stopped work since Android 4.2. I would like to know if there is a workaround.

Comment: i am getting this error, although i have added the permission, **android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION
                                              at android.os.Parcel.readException**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [Localization Library](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-LocalizationActivity/). from github