# How to enter RTL string for Android TextView

Tags: android, localization, persian, farsi

I have an Android application which I wrote for english language now I want to convert it to farsi/persian language. I want to know how can i type persian text for the TextView text.How can i maintain both the english and persian String.xml.please help.

cheers
Zolf

```
Locale locale = new Locale("fa-IR"); 
    Locale.setDefault(locale); 
    Configuration config = new Configuration(); 
    config.locale = locale; 
    getBaseContext().getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
```

where do i put this code,now i put this code in the OnCreate and it does not change the text of the TextView to persian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For showing correct form of Persian characters use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7962813/779408).

**Update**

And for changing current resources that is loaded in your UI:

```
tf = Farsi.GetFarsiFont(this);

tvTitle01 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTitle01);
tvTitle01.setTypeface(tf);
tvTitle01.setText(Farsi.Convert(tvTitle01.getText().toString()));
```

Comment: thanks for your comment.I had a look at that link and it works good for EditText and creating it from code. what I have is that my activity UI is build using xml and I want to put persian text for TextView which is in the xml file.how do i do it.

Comment: cheers,one question now my TextView looks like this in the xml   file.<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/customerName"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
        android:layout_gravity="right"/>

Comment: select an id for your view like this: `android:id="@+id/tvTitle01`

Comment: cheers mate it worked as expected. one thing,I have 2 folder values and values-fa. in the values folder i have eng text and in the fa folder i have persian text,but the problem is that the persian String.xml is not getting called.am i missing something.

Comment: `<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/customerName" android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:layout_gravity="right" android:id="@+id/tvTitle01"/> `

Comment: 'System.out.println("My locale::"+Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage()); 
   
 Locale locale = new Locale("fa");  
         Locale.setDefault(locale); 
         Configuration config = new Configuration(); 
         config.locale = locale; 
         getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics()); 
         Toast.makeText(this, "Locale in Persian !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
 System.out.println("My locale::"+Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage());'

Comment: Maybe your device does not support Persian language.

Comment: i am testing on the emulator,but in the System.out.println i get this "My locale::English
My locale::فارسی
"

Answer (score 1):

Android has built-in mechanism of localization.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

you can create the different folder of values as per language and can keep different  string.xml file for each language. Example:

`res/values/strings.xml`
Contains English text for all the strings that the application uses, including text for a string named title.

`res/values-fr/strings.xml`
Contain French text for all the strings, including title.

`res/values-ja/strings.xml`
Contain Japanese text for all the strings except title.

If your Java code refers to R.string.title, here is what will happen at runtime:

If the device is set to any language other than French, Android will load title from the `res/values/strings.xml` file.

If the device is set to French, Android will load title from the `res/values-fr/strings.xml` file.

Comment: thanksfor your comments.where do to set the language of the device.for e.g. i want to use persian/farsi font.

Comment: by code : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679574/android-is-there-any-way-to-change-the-default-language-of-android-to-new-lang

Comment: I have a TextView and want to change its text to persian text.how can i do it. in the String.xml when i change the english text to the perisan text it puts spaces between the character,this i am testing on gingerbread 2.3.3

Comment: sorry but not have idea about this, can try http://translate.google.co.in/?hl=en&tab=wT