# Change default phone language by changing application language in Android?

Tags: android

Is there any way to change language of phone by changing the language from application.

I mean when I change the language of my application then the default phone language will also change.

Is there any idea about this then please share here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess this is the same problem as here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679574/android-is-there-any-way-to-change-the-default-language-of-android-to-new-lang

Answer (score 1):

I dont know that it can be changed programatically, but after you changed your app language you can ask user to change device language also,

Ask user to change device language

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.LanguageSettings");            
startActivity(intent);
```

Change app language

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.SomeActivity"
    android:configChanges="locale"
    :
    :
</activity>


public static void setLanguage(Context context, String languageToLoad) {
    Log.d(TAG, "setting language");
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad); //e.g "sv"
    Locale systemLocale = SystemLocale.getInstance().getCurrentLocale(context);
    if (systemLocale != null && systemLocale.equals(locale)) {
       Log.d(TAG, "Already correct language set");
       return;
    }
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    Log.d(TAG, "Language set");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add **android:configChanges="locale"** to  your activity decalaration in AndroidManifect file.

Then call following method from onCreate of that activity .

```
public static void setLanguage(Context context, String languageToLoad) {
  Log.d(TAG, "setting language");
  Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad); //e.g "sv"
  Locale systemLocale = SystemLocale.getInstance().getCurrentLocale(context);
   if (systemLocale != null && systemLocale.equals(locale)) {
   Log.d(TAG, "Already correct language set");
   return;
 }
 Locale.setDefault(locale);
 android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
 config.locale = locale;
 context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config,context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());                                                            
 Log.d(TAG, "Language set");
  }
```