# Change device Language within my app

Tags: android, localization

I want to be able to change my phone settings within a button click inside my app. To be precise, I would like to change the phone's language. So far I created values/strings and values-iw/strings (hebrew strings) and within a button click I changed the configuration as follows:

```
    if (myLocale != null) {
        Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = myLocale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
```

This code changes the locale (I'm not sure about the difference between locale and language) but it does not affect all my activities. Thus, I tried to change the phone's language settings right from my app but did not manage to.
Does anyone have an idea how do I make this code affect all my activities? Or instead - how to change my phone language (reflection??)...

---

To make myself clear - I have Activity A which calls Activity B (I have many more activities all with
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
in AndroidManifest).
In activity B I changed locale language and returned to Activity A by the following lines:

```
    final Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
    finish();
```

The locale change does not affect Activity A (but affects all other activities, among them activity B). I assume the reason it does not affect Activity A is that activity A is still in the stack. I didn't manage to affect Activity A when changing locale. Does anyone have an idea how to affect also Activity A?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679574/android-is-there-any-way-to-change-the-default-language-of-android-to-new-lang

Answer (score 1):

> I want to be able to change my phone settings within a button click inside my app. To be precise, I would like to change the phone's language.

That is not possible, sorry.

> within a button click I changed the configuration as follows

At most, that will affect your app, not the "phone".

> Does anyone have an idea how do I make this code affect all my activities?

Run that same code in each activity, such as from `onResume()`.