# change my device language byc code but its not reflect in device

Tags: android

I want to change my device language programmatically and execute below code after if the device language isn't changed

```
Locale locale=new Locale("de");  //Chinese    
Locale.setDefault(locale);
```

How can I do that?

Comment: This is already answered in this stack [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679574/android-is-there-any-way-to-change-the-default-language-of-android-to-new-lang][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679574/android-is-there-any-way-to-change-the-default-language-of-android-to-new-lang

Comment: this is not my question that "how to change lang", i was asking that i tried to change my device lang but its not reflect on device why?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a fairly definitive answer to something i feel you may be misunderstanding. The method you are using will only set the language for the application context upon which you set the language configuration. Only your app will run with the new languages settings. A global change will require raised permissions and possibly root access.

Comment: yes, i was asking this. think you gusdor.

Comment: Feel free to flag it as the answer :P #RepAddict